# CSS class only applied after action happens

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router

I have a bit of a (very) weird issue going on. I've been trying to handle it for a while now, and decided to look for other thoughts on trying to fix this.

So, here's what's happening:

I'm developing a React app, using react-router. Every time that a new view is loaded, I use react-addons-transition-group to create a fade animation. And it works fine, overall.

The problem is that there's one view that, if coming from a specific view, will not load it's CSS classes. This is extra weird, since I have all the CSS classes in one single minified file.

The view in question is a carousel, that holds many views. First time it's opened, it has no style applied. However, if I change the carousel slide, all the styles are applied.

The following screen shot will show the state before and after the change of slides:

[image]

At this point, I'm completely out of ideas of what can be happening. Have anyone ever faced such issue?
I think I should stress it once more: it only happens when transitioning from one specific view to this specific view. It does not happen anywhere else in the app.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say without the code but look at div#app.

On the LHS you have <div id="app" class="app login-section />
and on the RHS you have <div id="app" class="app **calculator-section** gender />

and the styling requires that class as it is

```
.calculator-section .calclulator-slider .calclulator-entry {
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right. The class on div#app was not being updated, and that was causing the issue. Thanks for your help! I knew I needed someone else's brain. :D